# Getting a percent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have followed a few other similar posts on here but despite following some tips I am still not getting the result I expect

I have two variables: TimeTaken and TimeGiven. Both are stored as Int values (representing seconds)

When I output the individual values they come out correctly as integers

Example

TimeTaken = 4 and TimeGiven = 10

I then have a function to get a percent as an integer from the value. I have seen different ways and here are two of them:

Option 1

```
private fun getPercent(timeTaken:Int,timeGiven:Int): Int {

    return ((timeTaken.toDouble() / timeGiven)*100).roundToInt()

}
```

Option 2

```
private fun getPercent(timeTaken:Int,timeGiven:Int): Int {

    return (timeTaken / timeGiven)*100

}
```

When I am calling this e.g.

```
getPercent(TimeTaken,TimeGiven)
```

I always get 0 as a return when I output the result to a textview

To see the value in my textview (until I can prove it working) I am simply doing this(where TIMETAKitm.text has already been initialised as a view);

```
TIMETAKitem.text = getPercent(TimeTaken,TimeGiven).toString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
return ((timeTaken.toDouble() / timeGiven)*100).toInt()
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had also tried this variation. Why does this work when roundToInt() does not? I thought both effectively did the same thing? When does each one apply?

Comment: Well, round to int also works fine, don't know why it didn't work for you. toInt would cover all your requirement, but if you're specific about rounding on the basis of decimal points only than roundToInt comes in place it works just like floor and ceil, try this example https://pl.kotl.in/fI9AAIuu9

Comment: Well thank you. This has definitely fixed it